# App to replace my physical notepad?

Tags: android, ipad-app

I'm looking for an app that will allow me to record hand-written notes and diagrams using my tablet's stylus pen.  I find [Whiteboard Fox](https://whiteboardfox.com) excellent for this purpose except it requires an internet connection.

Is there an app that allows me to draw a diagram offline and then automatically sync to the cloud when I have an internet connection?

Comment: Android *and* ios, or is it an *or*?

Comment: Of course both would be good, but would settle for either at this stage

Comment: No personal experiences, hence just a short comment: For Android, you might wish to check [LectureNotes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.acadoid.lecturenotestrial), [Papyrus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.steadfastinnovation.android.projectpapyrus), and [HandWrite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.thoster.handwrite). Not sure whether any of them is available on iOS as well – not my area of expertise :)

Answer (score 1):

The app that comes to mind first is [Penultimate](https://evernote.com/penultimate/), however it seems to be limited to iPads only.

Another option is to get a surface pro and use the accompanying stylus with the [Microsoft OneNote software](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/office-apps/take-notes-with-onenote)

Comment: No need to buy a surface pro - seems thta OneNote has an Android app!

Comment: Katy, could you please check with [this meta post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) and then [edit] your answer to improve it? Answers should show a) how the recommended product matches the requirements, and b) what makes it recommendable (preferably personal experience). As it's currently phrased, it's rather a comment.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the feedback and sharing those links. I will try to improve the answer!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like Evernote and Microsoft OneNote have an Android app that fits the bill (maybe iPad app to but haven't checked).  Penultimate is also good for iPad.

Comment: Mark, could you please check with [this meta post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) and then [edit] your answer to improve it? Answers should show a) how the recommended product matches the requirements, and b) what makes it recommendable (preferably personal experience). As it's currently phrased, it's rather a comment.